# generate pdf from byte[] using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a new pdf file file and save it to disk using iTextSharp.

I have bytes[] for pdf content but unable to understand how to use this with iTextSharp.

```
public bool CreatePdf(string filepath, byte[] content)
{

}
```

Can anyone help me with some sample code to generate pdf using byte[] in iTextSharp and save it to disk.

I found lots of tutorial on google with adding new paragraph or chunk.. but I want to use byte[].

Comment: hmmm,, if all you have byte[] of content and if it supposed of pdf file's byte data, then why you need to create pdf through iTextSharp. You can directly write a file using memorystream or File class.

Comment: absolutely over thinking things. File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes) is the way to go

Comment: I tried but pdf layout doesn't look good.
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    fileStream.Write(exportedByte, 0, exportedByte.Length);
                    fileStream.Close();
                }

Comment: in short... data contains table structured data and in pdf file, if a cell contains multiline data, only first line is getting displayed

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. It might clear things up.

Comment: You say you have "bytes[] for pdf content" but that doesn't really make sense. If your byte array a PDF? If it is, write it to disk as Daniel said. If it doesn't look right, then _you do not have a byte array of a PDF_, you have something else. Inspect the byte array, the first four bytes should be `25-50-44-46` and the last (or almost last) bytes should be `25-25-45-4F-46`.

Comment: Thanks.... I got the issue...

my byte[] comes from microsoft reportViewer control (export to PDF) and I believe that the limitation of export to pdf, it does some manipulation with table layout like show only first line in cell (hide rest).

I updated my SSRS reports to return single line of data per cell and simple fileStream.write worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Cannot share PDF because of data confidentiality.

anyway, issue is resolved now. Thanks everyone for your help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool CreatePdf(string filepath, byte[] content)
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(content));
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create));
}
```

Comment: If your proposal worked for the PDF, the originally proposed writing of the byte array to disk would have worked as well and would have been way simpler.

Comment: @Alfonso Rogero, it gives error on the first line: "PDF header signature not found."